# invalidate doesn't call onDraw if the view is added later

Tags: android

I have a custom ViewGroup which has several child views which are also custom views. Calling `invalidate()` within the child view works fine, except for when I add the views outside the constructor of the ViewGroup. for instance, if an async task finished and `onPostExecute` causes a new view to be added. For that new view, calls to `invalidate` fail to cause the object to be drawn. Everything else in that view will works fine (I can see it, clicking on it works, if something else calls onDraw it changes), but calling invalidate simply does not cause `onDraw` to be called.

I've checked for long/expensive loops on the UI thread and there are none. Also, setting `setWillNotDraw(false)` in either/both child or parent does not work.

Here's the project (sorry it's big). https://github.com/PeterMitrano/Climb/tree/last_working_invalidate/climb . The parent view is `GymMapView`, and `RouteLabelView` is the child view for which invalidate is having strange behavior. The call back where I add the `RouteLabelView`'s that don't work is in `MapActivity.onGymsFound()`

I've spent about 8 hours debugging this, and I'm still clueless, so any help is appreciated.

**Update:** I've discovered it's actually because `layout()` isn't getting called, which only happens in `onSizeChanged`. So the question is, can I somehow force `onSizeChanged` to be called? Or should I manually call `layout` when the new child view is added?

Comment: Have you tried requestLayout() to force it to relayout its children?

Comment: I've tried calling it right after `addView`, but it doesn't call `onSizeChanged()`, and therefore `layout()` isn't called. Maybe it needs to be called somewhere else?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to make sure onSizeChanged is called?